# Sending/receiving messages in Erlang (Concurrency)

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming, erlang

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Write an Erlang function named respond that takes two parameters, a process ID named Pid and an Erlang item named Item. The function should send a message to Pid; the message should be a tuple with two elements: respond’s process ID and Item. Then, the function should wait to receive a message back. If the message it receives is true, then print “That is correct!” If the message it receives is false, then print “That is incorrect!” If the message it receives is an error, then print “There was an error in the input.” If the message is anything else, then print “Invalid message received.”

I have written the following:

```
respond(Pid,Item) ->
  Pid ! {Pid,Item};
receive
  true -> io:format(~p~n "That is correct",[]);
  false -> io:format(~p~n "That is incorrect",[]);
  error -> io:format(~p~n "There was an error in the input",[]);
  _ -> io:format(~p~n "Invalid message received",[])
 end.
```

The error that I am getting when I compile my code is as follows:

```
1> c(main).
main.erl:15: syntax error before: 'receive'
main.erl:2: function respond/2 undefined
error
```

What is causing this error? Also is my problem solving approach for this Question correct?

Answer (score 5):

You're really really close.

The issue is that expressions in Erlang are not delimited by `;`. They're delimited by `,`.

Try…

```
respond(Pid,Item) ->
  Pid ! {Pid,Item},
…
```

Also… a small-ish tip: *respond’s process ID* is not `Pid`. To obtain *respond’s process ID*, you should use [`self/0`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#self-0).